# Arquilian does not work with Wildfly 16 to run test

Tags: java, junit, jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

The POM. XML has within it the dependence of JUnit 4.12.
But after several modifications of Pom and Arquilian. XML does not work yet 
Arquilian-bom 1.4.1

XML Arquilian

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<arquillian
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
    <container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final</property>
            <property name="modulePath">C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules</property>
            <property name="serverConfig">standalone.xml</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class EventTest {


//  @Inject
//  EventDao eventDao;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        System.out.println("<<<< CREATE DEPLOYMENT >>>>");
        JavaArchive jar= ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"test.jar")
//                .addPackages(true, EventDao.class.getPackage())
//                .addPackages(true, IEventDao.class.getPackage())
//                .addPackages(true, Event.class.getPackage())
//                .addPackages(true, IEvent.class.getPackage())
//                .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml","persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        WebArchive war=null;
        war=ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class,"test.war");
//              .addAsLibraries(jar);
//      EnterpriseArchive ear= ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class);
//      ear.setApplicationXML("META-INF/test-application.xml");
//      ear.addAsModule(jar);
//      ear.addAsModule(war);
        return jar;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("<<< START TEST >>>");
//      Event event=new Event("name", "surname", "company", "emai", Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()), "eventCode");
//      eventDao.save(event);
//      assertNotEquals(event.getId(), null);
    }
```

ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata
The problem is when I go to do mvn clean install-Pwildifly-managed

```
<<<< CREATE DEPLOYMENT >>>>
10:34:05,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\18\d23c3d17787e29ad61b85dcbee31f55b62ee89\content
10:34:05,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
10:34:06,188 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.war
10:34:06,373 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.15.Final
10:34:06,813 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900: 3.1.0 (Final)
10:34:06,915 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.8.Final
10:34:07,345 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-5) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
10:34:07,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
10:34:08,049 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/test' for server 'default-server'
10:34:08,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
2019-04-09 10:34:08,594 DEBUG org.xnio.nio WorkerThread.java:429 [Remoting "endpoint" I/O-1] - Started channel thread 'Remoting "endpoint" I/O-1', selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@69a890a7
2019-04-09 10:34:08,646 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:173 [Remoting "endpoint" task-4] - Available version (Versions  0x00 0x01)
2019-04-09 10:34:08,654 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:179 [Remoting "endpoint" task-4] - Calling a stable server
2019-04-09 10:34:08,654 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:131 [Remoting "endpoint" task-4] - Selecting version 0x00 to receive full version list.
2019-04-09 10:34:08,666 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:173 [Remoting "endpoint" task-5] - Available version (Versions  0x01 0x02)
2019-04-09 10:34:08,666 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:179 [Remoting "endpoint" task-5] - Calling a stable server
2019-04-09 10:34:08,666 DEBUG org.jboss.remotingjmx.VersionedConectionFactory VersionedConectionFactory.java:194 [Remoting "endpoint" task-5] - Server version 3.0.1.Final
10:34:08,957 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/test' from server 'default-server'
10:34:09,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 163ms
10:34:09,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\18\d23c3d17787e29ad61b85dcbee31f55b62ee89\content
10:34:09,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.458 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(relational.EventTest)  Time elapsed: 0.1 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

Stack error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
        at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI(ServletUtil.java:61)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletURIHandler.locateTestServlet(ServletURIHandler.java:54)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:128)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:118)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:15)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:332)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:215)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:285)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:166)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: What version of `org.wildfly.arquillian:*` are you using? 2.2.0.Final is the latest.

Comment: yes 2.2.0  @PeterSmith

Comment: We solved, it was enough to add in addiction 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`
@PeterSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved, it was enough to add in addiction

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```